# VBA listbox created during runtime, not triggering event

Tags: excel, vba, events, listbox, userform

I've created a listbox from within vba code when certain combo box items are selected.
Basically when the combo box item is selected an SQL is run on a database table and the resultant recordset is fed into an array, which subsequently fills a multi dimensional listbox.

This is completed within the userform module the listbox is displayed on.
I've added a click and a double click event for the list box, but neither work.

The following code is used to create the listbox within the userform module.

```
        Dim lst As Control
        Set lst = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Listbox.1", "lstOutputList")
        Rows = UBound(OutputList, 2)

        With lst
                .Clear
                .ColumnCount = Columns
                    For x = 0 To Columns - 1
                    For y = 0 To Rows
                        .AddItem
                        If Not IsNull(OutputList(x, y)) Then
                            .List(y, x) = OutputList(x, y)
                            Else
                                .List(y, x) = ""
                        End If
                    Next y
                Next x
                For count = .ListCount To Rows + 1 Step -1
                        .RemoveItem count - 1
                Next count
                .BoundColumn = 2
                .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle
                .Left = 270
                .Top = 100
                .Width = Columns * 70
                If Rows > 50 Then
                    .Height = 300
                    Else
                    .Height = Rows * 13
                End If
    End With
```

The lists are created and displayed on the form absolutely fine, it's just the events that aren't firing.
I've tried both the lst_click() and lstOutputList_Click() events and the equivalent double click events, nothing works.

Comment: Why don't you simply add the ListBox at design-time, and toggle it's `.Visible` and `.Enabled` properties?  It's certainly possible to make dynamic listbox objects on the UserForm, but in this case it doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: The column count changes depending on SQL selected, that's why I'm dynamically creating it each time.

Comment: You can also change the `.ColumnCount` (and other properties) at run-time...

Comment: Typically, controls added at run-time are done when there is an unknown number of controls that need to be added (i.e., adding an option button for each row in the recordset resulting from the query, etc.).  These would be added to a class object with appropriate event handler.  But again, that doesn't seem necessary for this particular problem.